# Seeking a source for a claim about Rabbi Akiva

Tags: torah-study, moshe-rabbeinu, martyr, rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef

I saw in a modern book  as follows:

> דהנה איתא בגמ׳ דר׳ עקיבא היה לו מעלה יתירה ממשרע״ה אשר לו היתה הבנה גם בסודות הניגונים והטעמים, מכיון שמת במיתה משונה לכן זכה לזה המדריגה שמשה רבינו לא זכה לזה.‏
>
> the *g'mara* says that Rabbi Akiva had a level higher than Moshe *rabenu*, in that he had an understanding also of the secrets of the tunes and [cantillation(?)] notes: since he died with [torture] he merited this level that Moshe did not.

Does anyone know where this *g'mara* is? [*M'nachos* 29 *amud* 2](//www.sefaria.org.il/Menachot.29b) discusses some understanding that Rabbi Akiva had that Moshe did not, but doesn't* indicate that it had to do with tunes and notes, nor does it* indicate that he merited this level because he'd wind up being tortured to death. Perhaps some commentary there indicates one or both of those points? Or is there another *g'mara* that does so? Or some other (non-*g'mara*) source?

---

* as far as I see

Comment: See in sefer amud haavoda from rabbi moshe kosover chelek drashot drush hateshuvs alef, exists in old edition in Hebrew books

Comment: Although it's not 100% sure of course, but once I did a survey on cantillation in the Gemara, and I don't remember anything such being said. Maybe a commentary interpreted some words like this?

Comment: Try in avot derabbi Nathan. I have not it available for now

Comment: I assume the author got confused between _tagim_ and _taamim_.

Comment: The book דברי פתחיה sources this idea to that gemara in Menachot. It also mentions in relation "ובמדרש פליאה שלח נא ביד תשלח ביד מי ביד ר' עקיבא".

Comment: I also see that Rabbeinu Yonah explains ר"ע אומר...מסורת סייג לתורה As referring to the te'amim and punctuation which was still passed at the time בע"פ. A similar idea seems to be brought in Midrash Yelamdenu Yitro 2.

Comment: @Harel13 which דברי פתחיה is this? The collected writings of R' _P'sachya_ Lamm? If so, where in the book is it?

Comment: Yeah, that one. פרשת שמות דף י"ח.

Comment: @Harel13 I have a feeling that that parenthetical citation was added by the compiler-editor. I'm also very curious how you have a copy of the book, but maybe we should take that to [chat](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/468/vdibarta-bam).